# Не могу покдлючить Vertica к DBeaver на Debian, ошибка подключения 127.0.0.1 по порту 5433

Tags: sql, linux, localhost, dbeaver

Не могу покдлючить Vertica к DBeaver на Debian, ошибка подключения 127.0.0.1 по порту 5433 .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался открыть порт следующей коммандой:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5433 -j ACCEPT

root@debian:/home/rabovladelec/Загрузки#  sudo netstat -ntulp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      545/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:40817         :::*                    LISTEN      1800/java           
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:30675         :::*                    LISTEN      1800/java           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      545/cupsd           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52976           0.0.0.0:*                           541/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           739/dhclient        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           612/cups-browsed    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           541/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::40432                :::*                                541/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                541/avahi-daemon: r 

    root@debian:/home/rabovladelec/Загрузки# sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    4   240 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5433

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Прошу помочь.

Лог от коннекта Vertica к DBeaver :

```
июл. 10 17:32:34.402 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setLogLevel: Log level set to debug
июл. 10 17:32:34.402 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setLogPackage: Log package set to com.vertica
июл. 10 17:32:34.403 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setResultBufferSize: ResultBufferSize set to 8192
июл. 10 17:32:34.403 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setLoginTimeout: Login timeout set to 30
июл. 10 17:32:34.403 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setSocketFactoryName: Socket Factory Name set to 
июл. 10 17:32:34.403 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setSessionLabel: Session label is jdbc-10.01.0100-d322e946-503d-41ef-83b6-d16d89a31ed4
июл. 10 17:32:34.403 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setDirectBatchInsert: Direct batch insert disabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.404 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setUseStrictCatalogFiltering: Strict catalog filtering disabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.404 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setAddTzToTimestampParameters: AddTzToTimestampParametersdisabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.404 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setTLSMode: TLSMode set to DISABLE
июл. 10 17:32:34.404 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setUseThreePartNaming: Three part naming enabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.404 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setBackupServerNode: Backup server node set to 
июл. 10 17:32:34.405 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setConnectionLoadBalance: Connection load balancing enabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.405 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setJAASConfigName: JAAS config name set to verticajdbc
июл. 10 17:32:34.405 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setKerberosServiceName: Kerberos service set to vertica
июл. 10 17:32:34.405 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setKerberosHostName: Kerberos host set to 127.0.0.1
июл. 10 17:32:34.405 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setStreamingBatchInsert: Streaming batch inserts disabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.405 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setDisableCopyLocal: COPY LOCAL is enabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.406 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setEnableRoutableQueries: Routable queries disabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.406 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setFailOnMultinodePlans: FailOnMultiNodePlans enabled.
июл. 10 17:32:34.406 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setMaxPooledConnectionUses: MaxPooledConnectionUses set to 1000
июл. 10 17:32:34.406 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setMaxPooledConnections: MaxPooledConnections set to 20
июл. 10 17:32:34.406 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setMaxPooledConnectionsPerNode: MaxPooledConnectionsPerNode set to 5
июл. 10 17:32:34.407 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setMetadataCacheLifetime: MetadataCacheLifeTime set to 300
июл. 10 17:32:34.407 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setNodeDownWaitTime: NodeDownWaitTime set to 60
июл. 10 17:32:34.407 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.setPreferredAddressFamily: PreferredAddressFamily set to None
июл. 10 17:32:34.407 INFO  37 com.vertica.core.VConnection.connect: Connecting as user_db to test_db on 127.0.0.1:5433
июл. 10 17:32:34.408 INFO  47 com.vertica.io.VStream.establishConnection: Establishing connection to /127.0.0.1, port 5433
июл. 10 17:32:34.408 WARN  47 com.vertica.io.VStream.establishConnection: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1
июл. 10 17:32:34.408 WARN  47 com.vertica.io.VStream.establishConnection: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.VStream.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.VStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.ProtocolStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection$TaskConnect.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection$TaskConnect.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

июл. 10 17:32:34.409 ERROR 47 com.vertica.io.ProtocolStream.ProtocolStream: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.
java.io.IOException: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.
    at com.vertica.io.VStream.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.VStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.ProtocolStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection$TaskConnect.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection$TaskConnect.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more

июл. 10 17:32:34.409 ERROR 37 com.vertica.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100176) Failed to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 5433. Reason: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100176) Failed to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 5433. Reason: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.
    at com.vertica.io.ProtocolStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection.tryConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection$TaskConnect.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.core.VConnection$TaskConnect.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.NonTransientConnectionException: [Vertica][VJDBC](100176) Failed to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 5433. Reason: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.
    at com.vertica.io.VStream.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.vertica.io.VStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: перевёл обратно)), прошу прощения, не обратил внимания, что форум исключительно русский

Comment: 1. чтобы открыть доступ к порту, надо этот доступ сначала закрыть. вы же ничего не закрывали, верно? так что вы пытаетесь «открыть»??? 2. судя по выводу программы netstat, у вас в системе нет ни одного процесса, слушающего порт номер 5433. подключаться-то не к чему.

Comment: p.s. имя пользователя в приведённой информации может быть неправильно понятно особо активными афроамериканцами, владеющими каким-нибудь славянским языком. так что хорошо, что вы вопрос не публиковали там, где они могут встретиться.

Comment: охтыжблин..с именем пользователя не подумал,спасибо.

Comment: да, я нашел, что должен быть процесс, который должен слушать порт, тогда он будет отображаться, но весь вопрос как раз в том, что не могу подключить Вертику к Бобру по причине : "'Failed to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 5433. Reason: failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address (Connection refused)'"

Comment: @aleksandr barakin  попробовал telnet к этому порту - тоже неудача:                       
`  '# telnet localhost 5433
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
'`

Comment: если никакой процесс не слушает порт, вы не сможете подключиться к этому порту ни с помощью телнета, ни с боженькиной помощью (но это не точно). только хардкор, только слушающий процесс сможет ответить вам на попытку соединения.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin  к сожалению, я некрещеный. Спасибо огромное за разъяснение, но что делать с основной ачстью вопроса про подключение vertica к dbeaver, причину отсутствия подключения которого мне выдало как ""'Failed to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 5433. Reason: failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address (Connection refused)'"..Буду крайне признателен, если натолкете на ответ. Логи приложены к вопросу. Если порт открыт, то почему не даёт возможность подключиться по нему?

Comment: подключение происходит, собственно, не к порту, а к процессу, слушающему данный порт. если ни один процесс не слушает порт, на попытки подключения не будет ответа. это я уже третий и четвёртый раз повторяю в разных формулировках одну и ту же мысль. сколько раз надо повторить, чтобы вы поняли, что для того, чтобы процесс, слушающий порт, мог ответить на попытку подключения, этот процесс должен быть запущен (это уже пятая формулировка). могу продолжать вновь и вновь повторять одну и ту же мысль, пока мне не надоест, или вы не поймёте.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin  Спасибо за терпение. Вопрос и был в том, как запустить этот процесс, а не как послушать то, чего нет. Мне вообще параллельно, слушается порт или нет. Мне базу надо подключить. Т.е. запустить процесс, если к Вашим формулировкам придти.

Comment: вопрос ваш звучит совершенно иначе, но не суть: чтобы процесс слушал порт, его надо запустить. а чтобы было что запускать, надо что-то установить. вот с этого и начинайте: с установки dbeaver (или как оно у вас там называется? слышу, вроде, впервые).

Comment: @aleksandr barakin  Вопрос звучит не как установить dbeaver, а "Как покдлючить Vertica к DBeaver на Debian, ошибка подключения 127.0.0.1 по порту 5433". Ладно, спасибо и на том.

Comment: т.е. это самое «dbeaver» у вас установлено. отлично. следующий шаг — запустить «это» и убедиться, что запущенный процесс продолжает работать. следующий шаг ­— убедиться, что процесс слушает нужный вам порт (например, с помощью программы netstat). и уже только теперь можно переходить к подключению. дорогу осилит идущий.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, в данном случае dBeaver это DB Client, а Vertica это DB Server, поэтому запускать и конфигурировать нужно сначала Vertica )

Comment: @MaxU, т.е. сервер пытается подключиться к клиенту? куда катится этот мир… // или это автор вопроса перепутал направление подключения? впрочем, на последовательность шагов, изложенных в моём предыдущем комментарии, это не влияет.

Comment: DBeaver - это менеджер баз данных. Vertica - это БД. Vertica может быть как сервером, так и клиентом. Всем спасибо за помощь.